# $N_Q(R)=N_Q(Q\cap R)$ where $Q, R \le P$, $Q$ normal and $P$ a $p$-group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

Let $Q$ and $R$ be subgroups of the finite $p$-group $P$ and suppose that $Q$ is normal (maybe this is not needed).
Is it then true that 
$$N_Q(R)=N_Q(Q\cap R)?$$
Obviously, we have $N_Q(R)\le N_Q(Q\cap R)$, but the other direction is unclear to me. For suppose $y\in N_Q(Q\cap R)$ so that $Q\cap yRy^{-1}=Q\cap R$. From here, I do not see how to reach the conclusion $R=yRy^{-1}$ and in fact in general it seems to be false.

If the question is not true, do there exists some condition one can put on $Q$ or $R$ so that it is true?

Comment: I don't think there are any interesting conditions that would make the claim true. The left hand side describes the action of $Q$ on some arbitrary group $R$ and can be any subgroup of $Q$. The right hand side describes the action of $Q$ on a subgroup of $Q$ so is much more restricted. Perhaps you want something with commutators instead? If $Q$ is normal, then $[Q,R] \leq Q$ and $[N_Q(R),R] \leq Q \cap R$.

Comment: You may say $N_G(Q)\cap H= Q\cap H$ when $Q$ is sylow-$p$ group and  
$H$ is a $p$ group.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, this is not true in general. For example, we might have $Q \cap R = 1$ yet $Q$ does not normalize $R$.

For an example, consider a nontrivial semidirect product $G = R \ltimes Q$ (of two $p$-groups in your assumptions, but this is not really relevant here). Then $Q$ is normal, $N_Q(R \cap Q) = N_Q(1) = Q$. But $N_Q(R)$ is not all of $Q$, because otherwise $R$ would be normal. One particular example like this is given by the dihedral group of order $8$.

I don't know if there are any interesting conditions that would make the claim true.

Comment: I don't see how $R$ would necessarily be normal if $N_Q(R)=Q$. Why can there not exists $x\in P\setminus Q$ such that $xRx^{-1} \neq R$?

Comment: Because $P=QR$ and $R$ normalizes $R$.